# Getting string from phrase structure grammar

Tags: computability

For the following  phrase structure grammar I want to construct the type of string that satisfy it, but I am not sure the way to go.

$$\begin{align*}
S &\to xTy \\
T &\to xTT \\
xTx &\to xx \end{align*}$$

The thing I am struggling with is that I can't seem to be able to reduce it fully to the alphabet ($x$ or $y$) and the recursive nature seems to keep repeating the same irreducible pattern. For instance, here is what I tried

1. $xTy$
2. $x(xTT)y$
3. $xx(xTT)Ty$ (expanding left first)
4. $xxxTT(xTT)y$ (then expand right)
5. $xxxT(xTT)xTTy$ (expand middle)
6. $xxxxTTxTTy$ (simplify)

And then when I try to simply things again it tends to start it self again kind of repeating the process at step 2 again for the T's.

Comment: Are you sure the grammar is supposed to produce something? If this is an exercise, consider the possibility of it being a "trick" question. (If the productions of a grammar never terminate, then its language is the empty language, by definition.)

Comment: You can prove by induction that the rightmost $T$ is always adjacent to $y$, and so cannot be eliminated. Therefore the language is empty, as dkaeae writes.

Comment: Hmm, @glockm15 is an unregister user with 106 reputation. It looks like that user created the account with association bonus. Got 5 reputation from the upvote for the question. Then was the account deregistered but not deleted? Or is it a bug of Stack Exchange, which should be an unlikely event?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I don't know.  I suspect a bug. There may be a bug associated with the reverse situation as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278827/160917.